# How to specify an instrumental variable model with felm()?

Tags: r, regression

Due to implemented cluster standard error methods, I'd like to estimate an instrumental variable model with `felm()`. With `AER::ivreg()` and `plm::plm()` I can generate the same results. Specifying the function in `felm()`, however, doesn't seem very straightforward to me and I've failed.

I'm using the example of the `ivreg()` help, where `tdiff` and `I(tax/cpi)` both are instruments for `log(rprice)`:

```
library(AER)
aer.hat <- ivreg(log(packs) ~ log(rprice) + log(rincome) | log(rincome) + tdiff + I(tax/cpi),
                 data=CigarettesSW, subset=year == "1995")
> coef(aer.hat)
 (Intercept)  log(rprice) log(rincome) 
   9.8949555   -1.2774241    0.2804048
```

With `plm()` I could easily generate the same result:

```
library(plm)
plm.hat <- plm(log(packs) ~ log(rprice) + log(rincome) | log(rincome) + tdiff + I(tax/cpi),
               data=CigarettesSW[CigarettesSW$year == 1995, ], model="pooling")
> coef(plm.hat)
 (Intercept)  log(rprice) log(rincome) 
   9.8949555   -1.2774241    0.2804048
```

But I failed with `lfe::felm()`:

```
library(lfe)
felm.hat <- felm(log(packs) ~ log(rprice) + log(rincome) | 0 | log(rprice) ~ tdiff + I(tax/cpi) | 0 ,
               data=CigarettesSW[CigarettesSW$year == 1995, ])
> coef(felm.hat)
  (Intercept)         tdiff    I(tax/cpi) 
 1.000000e+00 -8.187404e-17 -3.294448e-17
```

How can we do this in `felm()`?

### data

```
data("CigarettesSW", package="AER")
CigarettesSW$rprice <- with(CigarettesSW, price/cpi)
CigarettesSW$rincome <- with(CigarettesSW, income/population/cpi)
CigarettesSW$tdiff <- with(CigarettesSW, (taxs - tax)/cpi)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

```
felm.hat <- felm(log(packs) ~ log(rincome) | 0 | (log(rprice) ~ tdiff + I(tax/cpi)),
                 data = CigarettesSW[CigarettesSW$year == 1995, ])
coef(felm.hat)
#        (Intercept)       log(rincome) `log(rprice)(fit)` 
#          9.8949555          0.2804048         -1.2774241
```

Point 1: instrumented variable `log(rprice)` only needs to be in the third part, no need to also add it to the first one.

Point 2: in the third part I added parentheses; `?felm` says something about interference between `~` and `|`, but I'm not sure why parentheses are needed in this case .

Also I removed `| 0` at the end, it is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Accordingly for models without covariates we can specify `felm(y ~ 1 | 0 | (d ~ z), data)`.